# Salesforce Error

Tags: ios, salesforce

Please help with below error. What could be the reason behind this error ?

> SFAuthenticationManager|oauthCoordinator idFailWithError: Error
>   Domain=com.salesforce.OAuth.ErrorDomain Code=666 "user is not admin
>   approved to access this app" UserInfo=0x17d4e5f0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=user is not admin approved to access this app,
>   error=OAUTH_APP_ACCESS_DENIED}, authInfo:

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more information than this.   When do you get this error?  looking at it Id say on login or attempting to do something which requires admin rights? Then Id say its a permissions error: "user is not admin approved"?  Provide as much information as you can so people can assist you better.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you are trying to authenticate but the user you are trying to authenticate doesn't have mobile (or remote, or whatever the setting is named) access from their org's administrator. You need your permission levels changed.

Comment: I checked user profile. User has permission set in salesforce.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the appropriate org (sandbox vs. prod)?